# special characters in drools rules

Tags: java, rules, drools

I'm using jBoss drools (v5.1.0) along with Tohu (also a jBoss product used to generate dynamic questionnaires).
The issue is drools and the special characters I want to put in the String in my rules. More specifically, I want to create/modify Objects in drools whose certain fields are strings but the special characters I put in those strings does not come out right!
For instance this code:

```
rule "UsecaseSelection"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop
    then
        Group aGroup = new Group("UsecaseSelection");
        aGroup.setLabel("Sélection du cas client");
        aGroup.setItems({
            "UsecaseSelectionQuestion",
            "UsecaseDescription"});
        insertLogical(aGroup);
end
```

will ouput a group with the label: "S?lection du cas client" (that is the special character "é" doesn't come out right)
I narrowed down this encoding problem to drools and I don't know if there is either a solution or a workaround as I really need those special characters in my project.
Thanks in advance for your help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRL files are currently read in the platform's default encoding.
So if you're reading the DRL file on Linux or Mac, make sure the file is encoded in UTF-8.
For windows, use CP-1252.

[This is a related issue.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2853)

Answer (score -1):

Use Camel framework and it's body converter:

```
    <camel:route id="tjtpRoute">
        <camel:from uri="direct:tjtpRoute" />
        <camel:to uri="drools:node1/tjtpKSession" />

        <!-- Since excel file is in windows Cp1252 encoding, we need to read it 
            in as such -->
        <camel:convertBodyTo type="String" charset="Cp1252" />
    </camel:route>
```